# DocuSign REST API. Changing user's email address possible?

Tags: docusignapi

I've tried this https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Users/Users/update#request and the PUT succeeds but doesn't change the user's email address.  Other attributes in the same body, e.g. jobTitle, update successfully.

It it possible to update an existing user's email address with DocuSign's REST API?

Thanks,
Graham

Answer (score 0):

The new email address requires validation. Can you check if an auto-generated email is sent to the new address to validate it. I think once the user clicks it and logs in to the account to confirm - it will be updated.